# How can i calculate the Euclidean distance between points on a dataframe with 4 columns and an array of x and y vectors for the points Using R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the Kmeans function manually, so I set the number of clusters to 3, the max iterations to sqrt(n), but I am stuck in figuring out how to loop around a dataframe with multiple columns and find the Euclidean distance between every point and every centroid I put randomly in "centroids"

```
    Iris = read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/iris.csv") 
    View(iris)
    Iris.features =Iris
    Iris.features$class <- NULL
    View(Iris.features)
     
    View(iris)
    
    k <-3
    max_iterations = sqrt(nrow(Iris)) #finding max iterations
    max_iterations
    max_iterations = floor (max_iterations)
    cx <- c(20,80,117)
    cy <- c(1,3,4)
    centroids <- array(c(cx,cy),dim = c(3,2))
```